# How to export and import the registry values form the previous version of the installer to current version of the installer using NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have created a new installer using NSIS. When installing this new version of the installer, if the previous version of the installer is present I am removing that installer and installing the new installer.

But before uninstalling the previous installer i wanted to store (export) the registry entries of the previous installer and then import (restore) the .reg file values with the new installer.

My Previous installer registry path is: \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\EMR\3.01.00

My Current installer registry path is: \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\EMR\4.01.00

**I am exporting (storing the registry values) like as shown below using NSIS:**

```
 ${registry::SaveKey} "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\EMR" "C:\Code\Changes\regfile.reg" "/G=1 /D=2" $R0
    ${registry::Unload}
    MessageBox MB_OK "PPC-registry::SaveKey$\n$\n\
                Errorlevel: [$R0]"

**Importing the registry values like as shown below:**
```

IfFileExists "C:\Code\Changes\regfile.reg" file_found file_not_found

file_found:

```
${registry::RestoreKey}  "C:\Code\Changes\regfile.reg" $R0

MessageBox MB_OK "PPC-registry::RestoreKey$\n$\n\
        Errorlevel: [$R0]"
```

goto end_of_test
file_not_found:
MessageBox MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK "File does not exist"
end_of_test:

But with the above code snippet when restoring the .reg file, in the registry it is showing EMR\3.01.00 AND EMR\4.01.00.
And also after the import, the sequence of the registry key values are changing.

Please help me how to restore the old registry values but show only EMR\4.01.00.

**Method 2:**

And also I am using the VB script to export and import the registry values like as shown below:

**Exporting the Registry:**

**Importing the Registry:**

```
  <Property Id="IMPORT_REG">
      <![CDATA[
                function importReg 
                  Dim regfile, userDir, oShell 
                  Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
                  userDir = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")    
                  regfile = userDir & "\tempkeyPCPE.reg" 
                  Return = oShell.Run("regedit /s """ & regfile & """",0,True) 
                  userDir = "" 
              end function
             ]]>
    </Property>
```

**Then using the WIX Installer, I am calling EXPORT_REG and IMPORT_REG like as shown below:**

```
<CustomAction Id="ExportRegistry" 
                  VBScriptCall="exportReg"
                  Property="EXPORT_REG" Return="ignore"/>


 <CustomAction Id="ImportRegistry"
                  VBScriptCall="importReg" 
                  Property="IMPORT_REG"
                  Execute="deferred" 
                  Impersonate="no" Return="ignore"/>
```

Please help me how to export and import the VB script calls using NSIS?

Comment: Maybe resolve your previous questions before asking another?

Comment: Do not vandalize your posts. By posting on this site, you've irrevocably granted the Stack Exchange network the right to distribute that content under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) for as long as it sees fit to do so. For alternatives to deletion, see: [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use `${registry::RestoreKey}`, use `${registry::MoveKey}` to move a key.

If you only support Windows 2000 and later you can also call the API directly:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include WinCore.nsh
Section
WriteRegStr HKCU "Software\Test\v1" "Hello" "World"
WriteRegDWORD HKCU "Software\Test\v1\Number" "" 42

!define /IfNDef MAXIMUM_ALLOWED 0x02000000
!define /IfNDef KEY_READ 0x20019
System::Call 'ADVAPI32::RegOpenKeyEx(p ${HKEY_CURRENT_USER}, t "Software\Test\v1", i 0, i ${KEY_READ}, *p0r1)i.r0'
${If} $0 = 0
    System::Call 'ADVAPI32::RegCreateKeyEx(p ${HKEY_CURRENT_USER}, t "Software\Test\v2", i 0, p 0, i 0, i ${MAXIMUM_ALLOWED}, p 0, *p0r2, *i)i.r0'
    ${If} $0 = 0
        System::Call 'ADVAPI32::RegCopyTree(pr1, p0, pr2)i.r0'
        ${If} $0 == "error"
            System::Call 'SHLWAPI::SHCopyKey(pr1, p0, pr2, i0)i.r0'
        ${EndIf}
        ${If} $0 = 0
            DeleteRegKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER "Software\Test\v1" ; Delete the old key (optional)
        ${EndIf}
    ${EndIf}
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Hi @Anders, It is working and changing the version from "v1" to "v2". And also if I change "Hello" to "World NEW" corresponding to "v1" manually in the registry, then to reflect the value in "v2', do we need to write "RegCopyTree" again? or else is there any way to change all the modified values corresponding to the root key?

Comment: You have to copy again.

Comment: Ok, got it. So for every value we need to copy again. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Anders, the sample code that you have provided is working fine. Here RegOpenKeyEx and RegCreateKeyEx are returning "0". But when I implemented this in my script,  RegOpenKeyEx and RegCreateKeyEx are returning "6" and it is not copying the registry values. If we get "6", is that the indication of failure?

Comment: I have written this logic in the Welcome screen leave function based on my requirement.

Comment: 6 means invalid handle. See "System error codes" on MSDN. Which HKEY are you using?

Comment: Did you remember `!include WinCore.nsh`? Try `MessageBox mb_ok ${HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE}` before  System::Call, it should say `0x80000002`

Comment: Maybe it removes the whole Test key? Copy the data somewhere else before uninstalling.

Comment: I have no idea what that is. Just copy it to "Software\TestBackup", uninstall the old, and then from there copy to "Software\Test\v2"